Write python results in an excel file, different columns
I know similar questions have been asked before, however, I cannot edit my code to fit:
I have a python script that writes all combinations of 15 numbers in a txt file:
import itertools
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(numbers, 15))
#print(combinations)

#Write combinations to a file
with open('combinations.txt', 'w') as f:
    for comb in combinations:
        f.write(str (comb) + '\n')

For some unknown reason, results come in parenthesis:

I need to write onto a xlsb file, each number in a column without parenthesis or commas, the expected result is below:

...with centralized text and fixed column width
Any ideas of a simple and small code? I already have pandas and openpyxl (if it helps)

Do you want an excel or text file (e.g. CSV)?

it needs to be excel (xlsb format). Please

you can't create xlsb files directly in python, you can however create an xlsx. Also, don't use pandas, that would be inefficient here, go directly for openpyxl (see my answer below).

If similar questions have been asked, why ask then and dont look up the similar questions?

does anyone tried https://github.com/rahulgurujala/excel-helper?

You can't create a xlsb file directly, you can however first create an xlsx file and then convert.
Note that you don't need pandas for that, better use openpyxl directly. Also, don't create all combinations with list, that will unnecessarily take a lot of space in memory if there are many combinations, rather loop directly over the output of combinations:
from openpyxl import Workbook
import itertools

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for comb in itertools.combinations(numbers, 15):
    ws.append(comb)
    
wb.save('combinations.xlsx')

To then convert to xlsb, follow this approach (which requires windows and Excel).
Output:


I do not understand why I get and error message:



from openpyxl import Workbook
import itertools
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for comb in itertools.combinations(numbers, 15):
...     ws.append(comb)
... wb.save('combinations.xlsx')
File "", line 3
wb.save('combinations.xlsx')
^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax




Sorry, it was just indentation... it worked

Here is what I have found on an old project with similar parameters, just need to import correct modules and possibly edit parameters etc.
import pandas as pd

# Convert combinations to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(combinations)

# Save DataFrame to an Excel file with a specified column width and centralized text
output_file = 'combinations.xlsx'
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False)

This should create a new excel file where each number occupies a single row and column. If this does not work, ill remove response.

helpful, did not save in xlsb and it did not centralize and adjust columns, but it worked.
